# Can Google Cloud Vision TEXT_DETECTION support to recognize multiple languages in one image?

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, google-cloud-vision

Please see the two test results.
There are two languages, but Cloud vision api always returns results in one language.
Could we tell which language(s) are expected in the image, so that the engine can try to find to recognize all characters even they are in different languages?

**1. Original image has three Chinese characters but was not recognized.**

[image: Original image]

**2. Then I tried to crop the image to make it has only Chinese characters.

The three Chinese characters can be recognized successfully.**

[image: Cropped image with Chinese only]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can tell the API which languages to expect.

According to the API's [ImageContext documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#imagecontext), you can direct the API to look for a list of particular languages for TEXT_DETECTION. Multiple values are accepted for a single image:

```
"languageHints": [ "en", "zh-TW" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for rmtheis's hint, and I apologize that I pressed "edit" mistakenly.
--
One note that setting ["en", "zh-TW"] does not really help. Instead, only "zh-TW" gets the desired result. Not sure this is the design or caused by some bug.

Document: [setLanguageHints][1] <br>
It said *For languages based on the Latin alphabet, setting language_hints is not needed.*

Comment: Here is the code:
    ImageContext imageContext = new ImageContext();
    String [] languages = { "zh-TW" };
    imageContext.setLanguageHints(Arrays.asList(languages));
    annotateImageRequest.setImageContext(imageContext);